# Show country specific borders from OSM in OpenLayers

Tags: openstreetmap, india

I use OpenStreetMap layer in OpenLayers for my ionic application. In it the country borders are not shown properly according to our countries claim.

How to show map borders specific to a country?

In this case India.

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Disputed_territories

Comment: For questions about open data and its characteristics/collation, I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.